# BLOB - что и зачем?

Tags: javascript, html5

не до конца понимаю, что такое BLOB в html... что с ним можно сделать и зачем нужно? примеры, если можно

Comment: Массив двоичных данных, которые обычно представляют какие-то файлы ( картинки, аудио, видео )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это двоичный файл, если рассматривать использование именно в html, а не js, то примером будет ссылки на стримы видео приходящие от своей или чужой веб-камеры (webrtc). Разумеется мы можем закодировать файл в base64 и вставить в страницу, но если файл генерируется (а не находится на сервере) большой или это стрим, то это уже проблема и для этого мы вставляем именно ссылку на этот объект в памяти, а не путь к файлу или закодированные в url данные Т.е.:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(vid);
```